# Why does Angular compile TypeScript interfaces to functions?

Tags: angular, typescript, interface, angular-library

I need to share some common interfaces between my NodeJS back-end and Angular front-end. So I created a new Angular project that contains only a library.

Here is an example of an interface:

```js
export interface EvPageRef {
    page_id: string;
    src_page: string;
}
```

If I compile the above with TypeScript 3.x it outputs nothing. There is no JavaScript output which is what I would expect, but if I add the above to an Angular library then I get the following.

```js
    /**
     * @record
     */
    function EvPageRef() { }
    if (false) {
        /** @type {?} */
        EvPageRef.prototype.page_id;
        /** @type {?} */
        EvPageRef.prototype.src_page;
    }
```

That is generated for the `umd`, `esm5` and `ems2015` source code folders in the `dist/example` project output.

Along side the above are the TypeScript type definition files which contain the `interface` declarations as expected which are in the `dist/example/lib` folder.

So I have two questions about this:

1. Why is this there and what's the point of it?
2. Won't this increase the size of an Angular project that uses this library?

Comment: The most weird thing is `if (false)`  so the function is literally useless.

Comment: @Angular Yes, and at first I thought this was a hack to add support for types in an IDE that only understood JsDoc, but then I noticed that the `@type {?}` is worthless but TypeScript knew that the type was `string`. None of it makes sense to me.

Comment: Don't close. This is not a broad or opinionated question. There has to be a specific technical reason for this. I can argue that no JavaScript output should be generated. That is not an opinion. It's because JavaScript doesn't have interfaces. Compiling interfaces in Angular has side effects, and I want to know why.

Comment: I guess it would be a good question issue on angular github

Answer (score 1):

The output of the JavaScript with interfaces as functions is created by [tsickle](https://github.com/angular/tsickle) which is a compiling middleware for Angular templates that generates code friendly to Google Closure.

https://angular.io/guide/angular-compiler-options#annotateforclosurecompiler

Why this is part of the Angular build process is unclear from the documentation. It also states that this option is `false` by default.

I updated my `tsconfig.lib.json` to disable the option, and now my JavaScript files are empty as expected.

**tsconfig.lib.json**:

```
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "annotateForClosureCompiler": false,
  },
```

This project doesn't contain any components so I'm comfortable turning this feature off, but I'm confused as to why the Angular Library generator enables this to begin with. The documentation doesn't explain what problem or benefit there is for this.

I'll still accept an answer which can answer why this was turned on.